# How to compile ARM EABI toolchain?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, arm, toolchain

i'm going to compile kernel for my aarch64 based device

kernel sources are ready.

and kernel docs are saying that i should use **arm-eabi-4.9 toolchain for ARM EABI** for compilation kernel.

but what is it? different type of GCC compiler or what?

is it same as [GCC 4.9](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/gcc-4_9-branch) ?

why i want to know this because i want to make some modifications into compiler so how can i build **arm-eabi-4.9 toolchain for ARM EABI** from source ?

i have made some research on the net but i found building process of gcc 4.9 and some info about arm-none-eabi..

i have made modifications originally on top of GCC 4.9 [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/gcc-4_9-branch)

can i use this sources and then building GCC 4.9 toolchain for arm,aarch64 ---> and then building kernel with using this toolchain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling gcc, some configuration flags build it as a cross compiler... You can only build gcc binaries for one pair of host/target architectures. When host and target are the same, you get a normal gcc compiler. If not, you get a cross compiler.

To set the target you need to add the [`--target` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html#TOC1) when running `./configure`

A toolchain is a gcc crosscompilier for an architecture + some basic libraries (like glibc). You'll need to build those too...

toolchain names go by  **arch [-vendor] [-os] - eabi**

*arm-none-eabi*, is a crosscompiler for baremetal ARM (no OS).

*arm-linux-gnueabi* is a crosscompiler for ARM binaries that'll run under a and ARM linux OS using eabi ( Use this for building kernels too).

Also those are **arm** toolchains, you're looking for *aarch64-linux-gnu*

Consider looking for a prebuilt toolchain (linaro, embedian), there is some fine tuning required, so it's better to start with a working binary, and running `gcc -v` to show how it was built.

Comment: thank you so much for reply and so can i modify/use the following gcc sources https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/gcc-4_9-branch and then configure for aarch64-linux-gnueabi before starting compilation and then compile the toolchain right?

Comment: Yes, `--target=aarch64-linux-gnu`. If that's not enough, compare your config settings to the ones used by [linaro toolchains](https://releases.linaro.org/14.11/components/toolchain/binaries/)

Comment: my host machine is ubuntu 14.04 so ı found the following 3 articles about how to build gcc compiler https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/08/26/building-gcc-on-ubuntu-linux/     https://raghunathlolur.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/cross-compiling-gcc-4-8-3-for-aarch64-port/        http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

Comment: 3 articles are different from each other...and really complex...which one do you suggest? which one is more close to my requirements?

Comment: and last one i will compile kernel for android(OS) so  can it create difference in --target config?

Comment: 1st guide is not for crosscompilers,  2nd guide is automated but not tested, 3rd guide was tested on qemu. I'd go with 3. Android uses bionic instead of glibc/newlib, everything is sort of the same up to building the kernel, but you need an androideabi toolchain for everything else (provided by the SDK)